# Convert big integer to byte array and vice versa

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, biginteger

In javascript i do computations on big integers, e.g. 61597086133919310755754988533408296568. I use a BigInteger library to make computations on those kind of numbers (https://github.com/peterolson/BigInteger.js). From my backend service i receive those numbers as byte arrays of the length 16 and i also have to send my calculation results back as byte arrays of the length 16.

Do you have any recommendation how to solve that properly?

Comment: please add an example of the byte array and the corresponding integer number.

Answer (score 2):

You could reduce the byte array by using a left bit shifting by `8` bits for a byte, then add the value.

```
var bytesArray = [255, 255, 255, 255],
    intValue = bytesArray.reduce((r, a) => r.shiftLeft(8).add(a), bigInt.zero);

console.log(intValue.toString());
```